# Removing/Restricting for wrapper by role

Tags: comments

I want to remove the div that holds the comment wrapper from a content type. What is the best wayto do this?

I could create a module, but I think I would only hode the form and not the headers that are inside the wrapper (just outside the form).

I guess I could hold it via the template, but I'm not sure how to pull the roles.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's Role based, why not remove the permission for that Role to View or Post Comments under admin/people/permissions?

If you need more granular control, try the Comment Permissions Module (https://drupal.org/project/comment_perm)